# Why Qwt extension does not work in Qt Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qt5, visual-studio-2022

Im currently woking in Visual Studio 2022 with Qt extension with MSVC 2019 Qt version 5.12.2 x64. I succesfully executed qmake in Qt Creator 6.4.0 and obtained build (msvc2019 x64) release folder. Then I ran nmake and nmake install which got me Qwt-6.2.0 folder in my C drive with doc,features,include,lib and plugins folders. I also added qwt_designer_plugin.dll to plugins designer. After that I tried to add qwtPlot in Qt designer but when I ran programme I get this error message:

Error message

[image: 1]

I tried to add libs and include files via project properties but nothing worked at all. Any suggestions please?

Comment: I use Qwt with no issue in Visual Studio 2019 but don't use 2022 because I would have to repurchase an addon I use daily to switch my IDE.

Comment: [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) has Qwt 6.2.0. You may want to use vcpkg to build Qt and Qwt for msvc. [https://vcpkg.io/en/packages.html](https://vcpkg.io/en/packages.html)

Comment: And it is working with just drag n drop qwtPlot in Qt designer ?

Comment: To be honest I don't believe I am using the QwtPlot in any current application at work. I use Qwt for some of the other widgets like QwtSlider.

Comment: I have progress in this problem. In release mode it works but debug mode is problem. I added two seperate folders with include and lib folders for both release and debug mode to VS but nothing changed. I tried to add it to on path previously. I delete the path to release version and restart computer but still debug not working.

Comment: If you previously used the release lib in debug mode it could certainly cause the crash since in msvc the ABI is different between release and debug. You can't safely mix the 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out myself. Note that Qt (as least up to the 5 releases) have a consistent naming of their files, modules and libraries: With or without a **d** suffix. If a DLL have a d suffix (like Qt5Cored.dll) then it's a library for debug builds, make sure you build with the debug libraries for your debug build.

So you just add qwtd.lib for debug and qwt.lib for release in Additional Dependencies.